# How to create a custom theme for telerik MVC grid?

Tags: grid, telerik-mvc

How can I create a custom theme for telerik MVC grid ?

need your helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Telerik Visual Style Builder.

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/visual-style-builder.aspx

Comment: can you tell me how to use it ? I only can change the color in visual style builder.

Comment: what exactly do you want to customize?